# When does the fraction $142/2.54$ ever repeat?

Tags: fractions, decimal-expansion

I recently measured my kid's height, and I found that it was $142$ cm. I wanted to convert this to feet and inches, so I divided $142$ by $2.54$, yielding an approximate answer of 55.905511811. I decided to look further, so I inspected the first $100$ places, hoping for a repeat. There were none. I was surprised by this, as most fractions tend to repeat after around $20$ places. I pursued on, to later find that after $20,000$ places, there were ***NO REPEATS***. I was stupefied, and I couldn't go any further, as my computer was struggling to keep up with the demand. I decided to rest for a bit and wondered how long will the decimal go on before I encounter a repeat? Obviously, it's not going to be an irrational number as $142/2.54$ is $7100/127$, which is a rational number. So, can anybody tell me when will the fraction $142/2.54$ repeat?

Also, [running this code here](https://tinyurl.com/4hrybzmn) (It won't work anymore, sorry) will produce the first 1000 places of $142/2.54$

By the way, this is my first question, so although this might seem impractical, can you help me out?

Comment: It has a period of $42$.  See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=14200%2F254)

Comment: It must repeat ... otherwise it would be irrational. ... Phew Wolfie says it does https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=142%2F2.54

Comment: The interesting question (if perhaps, not quite relevant to the forum) that I’m seeing here is: since the expansion repeats, why is your code wrong? I’m not sure, but I suspect that it’s because of the binary encoding of floating numbers, which can ever so slightly skew operation results – usually not a concern, but here you’re looking at very “insignificant” digits... (I don’t know otherwise why it would give the correct first ~10 digits otherwise). If this is indeed the case, you should remember to use the division algorithm with integers only.

Comment: @Mindlack I assume that’s the case... Weird though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\frac{142}{2.54}=100\times\frac{71}{127}$. Since $127$ is prime, it may well happen that the decimal expansion of $\frac{71}{127}$ is periodic with period $126$. But that's not the case. It turns out that it is periodic with period $42\left(=\frac{126}3\right)$. In fact,$$\frac{71}{127}=0.\overbrace{559\,055\,118\,110\,236\,220\,472\,440\,944\,881\,889\,763\,779\,527}^{42\text{ digits}}\ldots$$and then it repeats itself over and over.

Comment: You must mean $100 \times \frac{71}{127}$, no?

Comment: @Mindlack Sure! Sorry about that. I've edited my answer.